# Vue/Vuetify - breakpoints based on component size

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

As far as I can see, Vuetify allows you to define breakpoints based on ***viewport size***. Is it also possible to define breakpoints based on ***the size of the component***? E.g.

- when several components are shown on an overview page, it would use a more "compact" layout to be able to show the components side by side on large screens.
- when only one component is shown it could take up more space (on large screens).
- the "compact" layout could also be used when only one component is shown on a small screen.
- on small screens, the overview page could show several components vertically rather than side by side.

Or can you recommend a better approach to this?

Comment: Can you have a look into this doc : https://vuejscomponent.com/vue-breakpoints, and check if it helps you.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something more in the lines of Container Queries. I believe these work like instead of asking for the viewport size, it'll ask for the size of the nearest element tagged as a container or something.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such feature in Vuetify. However, you can always hide `v-col` containing the component and other columns will take up the freed-up space.

[image]

For example:
https://codepen.io/olegnaumov/pen/rNpzvEX

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot rely on global breakpoints (at least for changes based on the number of components), you can pass your component a `layout` prop that dictates the internal layout of the component.

`Widget component`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Widget</div>
    <v-row :class="{ 'flex-column': layout === 'vertical' }">
      <v-col> Column 1 </v-col>
      <v-col> Column 2 </v-col>
      <v-col v-if="layout !== 'compact'"> Column 3 </v-col>
      <v-col v-if="layout !== 'compact'"> Column 4 </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Widget",
  props: {
    layout: {
      type: String,
      default: "normal", // Options: ['normal', 'vertical', 'compact']
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Then, you can make use of two directives provided by Vuetify to compute the layout of the child components and parent container: `v-mutate` to watch for changes in the number of children (using the `child` modifier) and `v-resize` to watch for resize of the app.

`Parent component`

```
<template>
  <v-app v-resize="onResize">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row
        ref="widget_container"
        v-mutate.child="onMutate"
        :class="{ 'flex-column': layout_container === 'vertical' }"
      >
        <template v-for="n in show">
          <v-col :key="n">
            <widget :layout="layout_widget"></widget>
          </v-col>
        </template>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>


<script>
import Widget from "/src/components/widget.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Widget,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: 2, // Any other method to change the number of widgets shown
               // See the codesanbox for one of them
      container_width: null,
      widget_width: null,
      // Tweak below values accordingly
      container_breackpoints: {
        400: "vertical", 
        900: "normal",
      },
      widget_breackpoints: {
        200: "compact",
        500: "normal",
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    layout_container() {
      let breackpoint = Object.keys(this.container_breackpoints)
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .find((k) => this.container_width > k);
      return this.container_breackpoints[breackpoint] || "normal";
    },
    layout_widget() {
      if (this.layout_container === "vertical") return "vertical";
      let breackpoint = Object.keys(this.widget_breackpoints)
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .find((k) => this.widget_width > k);
      return this.widget_breackpoints[breackpoint] || "normal";
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setLayout() {
      this.container_width = this.$refs.widget_container.clientWidth;
      this.widget_width =
        this.container_width / this.$refs.widget_container.children.length;
    },
    onMutate() {
      this.setLayout();
    },
    onResize() {
      this.setLayout();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Note, this is not a production-ready solution, but rather a proof of concept showing the use of `v-mutate` and `v-resize` for this purpose.

You can see this [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/component-resize-so-z03nfc?file=/src/App.vue) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own, using `useResizeObserver` and applying size classes on the element, which can in turn be used to modify the CSS rules to itself and its descendants:

Example:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;

const vuetify = createVuetify();
const { useResizeObserver } = VueUse;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const el = ref(null)
    const size = ref('')
    useResizeObserver(el, (entries) => {
      const { width } = entries[0].contentRect;
      size.value =
        width < 600
          ? "xs"
          : width < 960
          ? "sm"
          : width < 1264
          ? "md"
          : width < 1904
          ? "lg"
          : "xl";
    });
    return { el, size };
  },
});
app.use(vuetify).mount("#app");
```

```css
.xs span {
  color: orange;
}
.sm span {
  color: red;
}
.md span {
  color: blue;
}
.lg span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.45/dist/vue.global.prod.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.1/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vueuse/shared"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vueuse/core"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="h-100">
      <v-row no-gutters class="h-100" style="background: #f5f5f5">
        <v-col
          class="h-100"
          cols="12"
          sm="6"
          lg="9"
        >
          <v-card class="h-100 pa-2" :class="size" ref="el">
            v-card: {{ size }} <br>
            window: 
            <span class="d-inline-block d-sm-none">xs</span>
            <span class="d-none d-sm-inline-block d-md-none">sm</span>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline-block d-lg-none">md</span>
            <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block d-xl-none">lg</span>
            <span class="d-none d-xl-inline-block">xl</span>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```